# Merging backgrounds inherited from different classes

Tags: css, background

I would like to have several classes (like `red`, `green`, `blue`) that creates a small colored square next to an element, for example

```css
div { display: inline-block; margin: 20px; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px dashed black; }
.square::before { position: absolute; display: block; margin-left: -10px; width: 8px; height: 20px; content: ''; }
.blue::before { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 8px, transparent 8px); }
.green::before { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 8px, green 8px, green 16px, transparent 16px) }
```

Now when I use `<div class="square blue"></div>` I get this result

[image]

And using `<div class="square green"></div>` produces

[image]

Now I would like to get this result

[image]

By using `<div class="square blue green"></div>`, but the green rule overwrites the blue rule. I know about multiple css backgrounds, but I want to use combinations of at least 6 different squares and creating 63 rules for that is a bit brute force.

Is there any way to achieve this without adding hidden HTML, building gradients by javascript or writing exponential amount of css rules?

Comment: No this would require multiple before pseudo elements and you can only have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS variables and one pseudo element can do this. Then assign the color using inline style to have any combination you want or use predefined classes:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  position:relative;
}

.square::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:105%;
  width: 8px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--c1,transparent),var(--c1,transparent)),
    linear-gradient(var(--c2,transparent),var(--c2,transparent)),
    linear-gradient(var(--c3,transparent),var(--c3,transparent)),
    linear-gradient(var(--c4,transparent),var(--c4,transparent)),
    linear-gradient(var(--c5,transparent),var(--c5,transparent)),
    linear-gradient(var(--c6,transparent),var(--c6,transparent));
  background-size:100% calc(100%/6);
  background-position:
    0 calc(0*100%/5),
    0 calc(1*100%/5),
    0 calc(2*100%/5),
    0 calc(3*100%/5),
    0 calc(4*100%/5),
    0 calc(5*100%/5);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.blue {--c1:blue;}
.red {--c2:red;}
.green {--c3:green;}
.yellow {--c4:yellow;}
.purple {--c5:purple;}
.black {--c6:black;}
```

```html
<div class="square blue"></div>

<div class="square blue green red"></div>

<div class="square blue yellow purple red"></div>

<div class="square" style="--c5:black;--c4:red;--c3:blue;"></div>

<div class="square yellow purple" style="--c1:black;--c2:red;--c3:blue;--c6:red"></div>
```

Comment: This taught me the concept of non-global CSS variables, nice lesson!

Comment: There is also a catch that confused me (hope to help others): it is important to place `background-repeat` after `background`, otherwise `background` resets the default repeat.

Comment: @JanTuroň or change the background to background-image to avoid this ;) (Updated). I always use background because it's shorter and because sometimes I put all the properties there, ex: https://jsfiddle.net/yxj0912k/

Comment: #MeToo, I just often forget about the defaults and then wonder about it again and again. Hopefully next time I will be googling about it, google will show me this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You might do this with CSS variables.
The difference between @TemaniAfif's answer and mine is that I use variables to store `background-position` values, instead of colors:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.square::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 8px 8px;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(#00f 8px, #00f0 8px),
    linear-gradient(#0f0 8px, #0f00 8px), 
    linear-gradient(#f00 8px, #f000 8px);
  --b: 0 -10px;
  --g: 0 -10px;
  --r: 0 -10px;
  background-position:var(--b), var(--g), var(--r)
}

.blue::before {--b: 0 0}
.green::before {--g: 0 8px}
.red::before {--r: 0 16px}
```

```html
<div class="square blue"></div>
<div class="square green"></div>
<div class="square red"></div>
<div class="square blue green"></div>
<div class="square green red"></div>
<div class="square blue red"></div>
<div class="square blue green red"></div>
```